# PHP-FPM with dedicated error log file

Tags: logging, php

I've set up an Apache2/PHP-FPM site and would like PHP-FPM's errors to be logged to its own error log file. However, with the current configuration, the errors are being logged to /var/log/php5-fpm.log in the following format:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 22926 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /var/www/site.com/error.php on line 1"
```

In my /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf I have the following options:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
catch_workers_output = yes
```

When I disable `catch_workers_output`, the error logging ceases completely. However, in phpinfo() output, it is showing the logfile I specify in the configuration.

Why is PHP5-FPM not respecting this logfile. Is there any way to have errors for the fpm pool logged in a separate file?

My php version:

```
# php5-fpm  -v
PHP 5.4.9-4~precise+1 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Nov 30 2012 10:48:01)
```

Thank you for any information!

Comment: Every site should have its own error log. Why don't you just apache error logging for every domain/site, and error_log in php for every domain/site ?

Comment: There is an Apache error log, and it does get FastCGI error output from PHP. However, PHP will not isn't logging to what's being reported in the phpinfo() output for error_log--the file it displays isn't created. (Default, /var/log/fpm-php.www.log)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll find the error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log in your main FPM Configuration. Based on your example you are setting this in a Pool configuration, which will only work for that specific pool/domain.

Comment: Thank you! I'll read more into FPM pools. I still find it strange the phpInfo() is reporting that I'm using settings I define in that pool..

Comment: Don't forget you can always find some additional help in the FreeNode IRC Channel #php-fpm

Comment: `ERROR: [/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:440] unknown entry 'error_log'` ?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski without seeing your configuration it looks like you put error_log as a variable in your config file where it should probably have been php_admin_value[error_log]