# Request returns 408 on remote machine

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have docker containers for nginx + php-fpm on my home PC on port 8080. Nginx proxies requests to PHP scripts through FCGI and PHP-FPM.

It listens for requests with POST field named `data` and consist of JSON decoded array. For testing purpose i have JSON string which 1552 chars long.

When I make request using PHP cUrl from local macine e.g. `http://localhost:8080/path/on/site` I get my `data` field in my PHP app successfully.

But! If I making request from remote PC using totally the same PHP cUrl script except IP address (`http://myhomePcIp:8080/path/on/site`) - I got nothing.

In the nginx's access log I got:

`remoteIp - - [26/Jun/2018:04:07:55 +0000] "POST /path/on/site HTTP/1.1" 408 25 "-" "-"`

On the php-fmp side I have no request at all.

Trimming the length of `data` fields I got successful result with length 1289 chars, but 1290 chars ruined request totally.

Here the PHP script:

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://myHomePcIP:8080/path/on/site',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("data" => '<LONG JSON STRING>')
);

curl_setopt_array($c, $opts);
var_dump(curl_exec($c));
```

Comment: Why is the `myhomePcIp` the same for when you remotely access the page and for the PHP script `CURLOPT_URL`?

Comment: @JamesWong, `totally the same PHP cUrl script except IP addres` - for localhost I use localhost, for remotely i use external IP address of my home PC

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like php cURL is the source of the problem. I'd recommend you to check the following flags in your `php.ini` runtime file

> `max_input_vars` How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). [[Default = 1000]](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)
>
> `post_max_size` Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. [[Default = 8M]](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Set them to the following property

```
post_max_size = 8M
max_input_vars = 2000
```

If you have bigger json data package to process, you could increase the `max_input_vars` even more.

PS: It might be useful to enable php log:

- [Where is php-fpm log file? Or how to activate it? Does PHP7 log errors?](https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/48)
- [PHP-FPM doesn't write to error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log)
- [PHP-FPM with dedicated error log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344316/php-fpm-with-dedicated-error-log-file)

Comment: 30M and 5000 are set as post max and max input and no luck, php log is enabled by default in the docker php image. PHP's logs are emty for that failed request, but nginx has 408 Timeout response in access log (nginx error log is emtpy).

Comment: Looks like PHP fcgi is not responding, or idk

Comment: When you are accessing from a remote location, is it on a different network or is it on the same LAN? Am wondering if there are any issues with your router.

Comment: No, they are on the different LANs. My PC in the DMZ on the router.